# Ubuntu 14.04 installation doesn't recognize Windows 8.1 partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, asus

I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit alongside Windows 8.1 64-bit for several hours, but i can't seem to find the solution to actually installing it without removing my Windows 8.1 from the hard drive. The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize my Windows 8.1 on the hard drive and it show the whole hard drive as it is empty. 
I have both tried installing it with CD and USB-drive. The outcome is still the same.

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

GParted error message :

[image]

Some notations:
1) My Windows 8.1 seems to be operating on Legacy BIOS mode, because when i last checked 'Disk Management' it showed no sign of EFI System Partition.

2) With both CD boot (with WUBI the same) and USB-drive boot i get a black screen with an error saying 'could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14' before getting the menu options choosing if i want to try or install ubuntu. But i can still continue the procedure.

3) I have tried making partitions inside Windows with 'Disk Management' tool, partitions still don't show up.

Comment: Did you try to install ubuntu with wubi? You can find wubi inside the ubuntu iso when you are on Windows.

Comment: Wubi didn't work.

Comment: What do Ihave to do, please help?!?